# Getting issue in subproject entity in Android studio react native

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

i want to give reference of my subproject gradle plugin to my project level gradle so below is my code

**android/build.gradle**

```
 buildScript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        maven{
          url 'https://maven.google.com'
          name 'Google'
        }
        google()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        }
     }
    allprojects {

      repositories {
           configurations.all {
             resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->def requested = details.requested
              if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                 details.useVersion '11.8.0'
               }
              if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                  details.useVersion '11.8.0'
                }
              }
            }
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven {
               url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
             maven {
              url 'https://maven.google.com/'
              name 'Google'
                }
               }
              }

            ext{
            buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
            minSdkVersion = 16
            compileSdkVersion = 27
            targetSdkVersion = 26
            supportLibVersion = "27.1.0"
            googlePlayServicesVersion = '15.0.1'
            firebaseCoreVersion = '16.0.1'
            firebaseMessagingVersion = '17.3.0' 
           }
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
      compile project(':react-native-admob')
      compile project(':react-native-fcm')
     }
```

When i run above code i got error like **For input string: "+"** which is assign in react-native-admob plugin gradle file as below

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

so any idea how can i solve this issue? your all suggestions are appreciable

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is :

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

---

**P.s:** `+` is only used when you have set a version at first(*like 15.0.+*) and you need to give it the ability to have other versions support in future. Also, ***this is not recommended by Most IDE's*** so, use the latest version with number and not `+`.

Comment: I am integrate react native and my library project is in node_modules which is never commit in my git account so i want to give reference my subproject module library version in my project level gradle so which way i can give?